# Unable to change horizontal JSplitPane to a vertical

Tags: java, swing, panel, jsplitpane

Im using JFrame and its not possible to change my JSplitPane from the default horizontal to a vertical look. I have tried to do as below but the splitpane doesnt change..

```
jSplitPaneTest = new javax.swing.JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
```

and

```
setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
```

Is there anything else I can try? Im doing this from the "Customize Code" mode and nothing happends when I press OK. Would appreciate some kind of advice on this.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    contentPane.add(splitPane);
```

This works just fine for me.
Can you try it exactly this way and give me a response?
Otherwise please post more code.

Comment: There is no reason to call `setBounds` unless you have removed the contentPane's layout manager, which no one should be doing.

Comment: Oh, I´m sorry, just tested with some layouts and ended up with the absolute one. By copying the code i don´t noticed it. But now I´ve corrected it.

Comment: Hm, the code doesnt give me any error or something that indicates and problem. Just to clarify how im doing: I have created a JSplitPane in design mode. Right click on the splitpane and choose Customize code. In there I write the code. 
jSplitPaneTest = new javax.swing.JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
jSplitPaneTest.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
contentPane.add(jSplitPaneTest);
And then I press OK. And nothing changes. The splitpane is still horizontal.

Comment: First you can change the orientation also in the design view in the properies. If you want to write it in the code, you only have to add JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT **once**. So rewrite the jSplitPaneTest = new javax.swing.JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT); jSplitPaneTest.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT); into jSplitPaneTest = new JSplitPane(); jSplitPaneTest.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT); as I said above.